Firebase Record Robo Script Not Working in Android Studio
I want to record Robo Scripts by interacting directly with the app in my emulator. I followed the instructions in the official documentation.
I did what the documenation did, select tools -> Firebase, clicked the Record Robo Script and Use it to Guide Robo Test, and then Record Robo script. The Deployment Target dialog should appear; however I am not seeing any Deployment Target dialog, but rather Record Your Robo Script dialog.

I tried to interact with my app, but nothing was recorded. I am using the current version of android studio (koala) in my M2 MacBook pro.
